# Fragment listview pushes button out of the screen

Tags: android

What I want is that my framelayout is positioned all over the screen untill it reaches my button that stands on the bottom of the screen.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Compose"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The only problem is that I load a fragment in the framelayout and that contains a listview. Now when the listview gets to big it pushes my button out of the screen.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.test.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottomButton">
    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/bottomButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:text="Compose"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thought it would be enough to say that the button was under the framelayout. But you also need to do it in the otherway :)